# How to enforce rule SA1122 in visual studio editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

I am using Visual Studio 2022. My project has `.editorconfig` file found next to the solution file. I want to set the severity of rule [SA1122](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1122.md) to `suggestion` so that if I use `""` Intellisense would suggestion to use `string.Empty` instead.

Per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022#configure-severity-levels) I should be able to configure the severity using `dotnet_diagnostic.<rule ID>.severity`. I edited `.editorconfig` file and added the following line at the very end

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1122.severity = suggestion
```

However, I get no hint when using `""` suggestion that I should use `string.Empty` instead.

I also tried to use `warning` and `error`. Neither of them seems to have any effect.

How can I enforce rule [SA1122](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1122.md) for C# in visual studio 2022?

Comment: to make sure, you did add the package to your project? as is described in the readme.md? https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers#installation

Comment: @RandRandom thanks for that tip. I was not aware that I needed to explicitly install this project. I just added it. Now I am getting lots of errors in the project. It's enforcing lots of unwanted rules. How can I only enforce what is being added to the `.editorconfig` file`?

Comment: try `dotnet_diagnostic.category-Readability_Rules.severity = none` (before you define the individual items)

Comment: but now that the warnings are displayed, the lightbulb should help you out to configure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022#set-rule-severity-from-the-light-bulb-menu